# Android Nexus 4 Alarm Menu

Tags: android, calendar

I'm creating a recurring event manager for an application, and I want it to basically look identical to the alarm clock manager for the Nexus 4 phone. I need to be able to select time, the day of week, turn the alarm on and off, and select vibrate or tone. I can add the calendar integration myself.

I was wondering if this exists already, or if it's possible to access the code for the nexus implementation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Mark

Comment: There is no sources of `Alarm Clock` from Nexus 4. This app consists of several parts. Which exactly you want to implement?

Comment: The whole create alarm functionality is fantastic. Having the list of entries, and being able to add new ones, and set the time, freq, and type of reminder. I'm feeling lazy and I don't want to make it myself. But if it comes down to it, I will.